# MPI Fortran synchronizing data

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I have program that i working on parallelize using MPI. I have attached the test code, which breaks down the array into multiple segement along a given number of processor and then i am using broadcast to combine the results from all of the processes and give it out to all of the processes. The problem occurs when the distribution is not same along all of the processors and causes broadcast to fail. I have attached the following code that works with 6 processes, but not 8 processes.

```
  program main

  include 'mpif.h'

  integer i, rank, nprocs, count, start, stop, nloops
  integer err, n1
  REAL srt, sp
  REAL b(1,1:10242)
  REAL c(1,1:10242)
  integer, Allocatable :: jjsta(:), jjlen(:)
  allocate (jjsta(0:nprocs-1),jjlen(0:nprocs-1))
  call MPI_Init(ierr)


  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nprocs, ierr)

  n1 = 10242
  call para_range(1,n1,nprocs,rank,start,stop)
  jjsta(rank) = start
  jjlen(rank) = stop -start +1
  srt = MPI_WTIME()
  do i=start,stop
    c(1,i) = i
  enddo
  sp =MPI_WTIME()
  print *,"Process ",rank," performed ", jjlen(rank), &
         " iterations of the loop."
  !      CALL MPI_ALLGATHERV(c(1,jjsta(rank)), jjlen(rank), MPI_REAL,&
  !          b,jjlen(rank),jjsta(rank)+jjlen(rank)+1,MPI_REAL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
  CALL MPI_BCAST(c(1,jjsta(rank)), jjlen(rank), MPI_REAL,&
       rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
  deallocate(jjsta,jjlen)
  end program main


subroutine para_range(n1, n2, nprocs, irank, ista, iend)
integer(4) :: n1 ! Lowest value of iteration variable
integer(4) :: n2 ! Highest value of iteration variable
integer(4) :: nprocs ! # cores
integer(4) :: irank ! Iproc (rank)
integer(4) :: ista ! Start of iterations for rank iproc
integer(4) :: iend ! End of iterations for rank iproc
iwork1 = ( n2 -n1 + 1 ) / nprocs
!    print *, iwork1
iwork2 = MOD(n2 -n1 + 1, nprocs)
!    print *, iwork2
ista = irank* iwork1 + n1 + MIN(irank, iwork2)
iend = ista + iwork1 -1
if (iwork2 > irank) iend = iend + 1
return
end subroutine para_range
```

and when i run it with 8 processors with MPI_Bcast commented out and this is what it prints out this and it works

```
 Process             2  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
 Process             1  performed          1281  iterations of the loop.
 Process             4  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
 Process             5  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
 Process             3  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
 Process             6  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
 Process             0  performed          1281  iterations of the loop.
 Process             7  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
```

But when i try to combine all of the results and broadcast that this is the error i get

```
Fatal error in MPI_Bcast:
Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Bcast(1128)...................: MPI_Bcast(buf=0x2af182d8d028, count=1280, MPI_REAL, root=4, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
knomial_2level_Bcast(1268)........:
MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found(259): Message from rank 0 and tag 2 truncated; 5124 bytes received but buffer size is 5120
Process             4  performed          1280  iterations of the loop.
```

I also tried the MPI_Allgatherv to combine the result in array b and i get the following error:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Allgatherv:
Message truncated, error stack:
MPI_Allgatherv(1050)................: MPI_Allgatherv(sbuf=0x635df8, scount=1280, MPI_REAL,     rbuf=0x62bde8, rcounts=0x2b3ff297b244, displs=0x7fff3ebc1fb0, MPI_REAL, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Allgatherv(243)................:
MPIC_Sendrecv(117)..................:
MPIDI_CH3U_Request_unpack_uebuf(631): Message truncated; 5124 bytes received but buffer size is  5120
```

The problem when combining the arrays to me seems like that it is not updating the length of the array being sent. I can't seem to figure out how to solve the problem any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick guess: allocation of jjsta and jjlen before the nprocs has been determined?

Comment: From your question and glancing at the code, what you intend to do is gather pieces of array `c` from each process to all processes. This functionality is provided by `MPI_Allgather`. Also, I guess this is just an example code, but filling `c` in this case should be done without any communication by just looping over the whole array.

Comment: This can't be the program you are trying to run as n1 is a variable in the main program yet it is being used to dimension c which is not legal Fortran and not supported by any compiler I know. What value do you expect n1 to take?

Comment: Sorry but the new code can't be correct for a couple of reasons. Firstly you are using nprocs to dimension jjsta and jjlen before you have called mpi_comm_size to get the value. Secondly when using more than 1 process each call to mpi_bcast will have a different root. Remember bcast sends data from a single process to all the other processes within the communicator, so corresponding calls to bcast with different roots doesn't make much sense. This may the cause of the mpi_bcast error you report, though I have to say I would have expected deadlock.